# AdView shows only test banner on emulator

Tags: android, admob

I've just created an account on AdMobs, created banner for test.

The code is from BannerExample, without addTestDevice(...)

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private AdView mAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    // Gets the ad view defined in layout/ad_fragment.xml with ad unit ID set in
    // values/strings.xml.
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);

    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
    // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test ads on this device."
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

activity_my.xml

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-6784520601040456/7994286128" />
```

But I see only Test banner, when I launch the application.

Should I specify something else, to see the real banner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check it out in real device. Add usually doesnt show in emulator.